# tail -f pipe not only the single line

Tags: grep, pipe, tail

I would like to pipe log file with `tail -f` but only the last line. My command is

`tail -f logfile.log | while read line; do /usr/bin/gammu --sendsms TEXT ****** -text "$line"; done`

I saw that I can use `grep --line-buffered` but my new line can't have any char and with what I have tried it doesn't work.

Comment: `tail -1f logfile.log`?

Comment: @minitech Thanks for your help. But it doesn't work. `user@machine:~# tail -1f log.log | while read line; do echo "$line"; done`
`Line 2` #I update the log file
`tail: /var/log/apache2/access.log: file truncated`
`Line 1`
`Line 2`
`Line 3`

Comment: Tail will complain that the file is truncated when you truncate a file (`cat /dev/null > /file`), delete a file and create a new file (`rm file; touch file`) or overwrite a file (`cp file2 file`).

Comment: @alvits Thanks that finaly did the tricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows the problem is other place, which you don't show to us. 
Below test code is fine for me.

```
tail -1f logfile.log | while read line
do 
   echo /usr/bin/gammu --sendsms TEXT ****** -text "$line"
done
```

Comment: thanks. With your help and the help of @alvits it finally works. I append line to my log file with `echo "hello world" >> lofgile.log`